# add_image_size function not working

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

In functions.php i have,

```
function university_features() {
add_theme_support('title-tag');
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_image_size('professorLandscape', 400, 260, true);
add_image_size('professorPortrait', 480, 650, true);
add_image_size('pageBanner', 1500, 350, true);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'university_features');
```

In single-professor.php, I have:

```
<div class="one-third">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('professorPotrait'); ?>
 </div>
```

But the image size doesn't change. But, if I put the default size of "thumbnail" or any of the others like this:

```
    <div class="one-third">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
    </div>
```

it works. What could be the issue? I'm working on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

All images before you added new image size will not be resized. You must regenerate all thumbnails. There are lots of thumbnail regeneration plugins that you can use.

Comment: I know that. But if i add a new post and thumbnail after writing this code, it should work, right? It's not working.

Also, when I use the regenerate thumbnails plugin, it gives the following error:

This tool won't be able to do anything because your server doesn't support image editing which means that WordPress can't create thumbnail images. Please ask your host to install the Imagick or GD PHP extensions.